# How do I include another PHP file that is stored as a variable?

Tags: php, include

I'm trying to load another page using the include statement but I keep getting the error:

```
Warning: include(AccountView.php?id=) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/public_html/InsertAccount.php on line 62
```

---

```
$return = "AccountView.php?id=".$ID;
include $return;
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing to make this perform correctly.  Another set of eyes would really be great.

Comment: When you include a local file, you can't use GET parameters

Comment: Do you have a file called “AccountView.php?id=” on your server?

Comment: As an addendum to @Pekka웃's comment, when you include a PHP file, it will receive all variables in scope at which the include statement is executed. You could use your `$ID` variable that way.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do an `include` and not a redirect?

Answer (score 1):

There's no file with this name:

```
AccountView.php?id=
```

The `?id=` part is killing you. You're trying to include an URL there, not a filename.

Comment: Thats correct, sorry.  I am trying to include the url with the variable $return.  Yes, the file exists and is functioning correctly.  I'm trying to return to that page after performing an update to a table.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a file called `AccountView.php?id=.php`, this won't work.

What you want to do is set the variable (`$ID`), include your file and then use `$ID` in the included file:

```
$ID = '5';
$return = "AccountView.php";
include $return;
```

Comment: Thanks!  How would I pass the variable $ID to the next program?

Comment: @user2055499 It's within the scope of your parent script. You would just call it in `AccountView.php`